# How to insert an image/graphic below the legend keys?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

Is it possible to insert something like this under my legend using ggplot?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly everything is possible. Here, I would probably call this an annotation rather than a legend. Annotations work like any other plot element. It just needs a bit of experience how to implement this (there are a few things to consider - see my comments in the code).

Another option is to create the annotation as a separate plot and overlay them with another package (cowplot is really good for that, but patchwork works too).

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(type = c("vision", "video"), date = as.Date(c("1950-07-02", "2022-09-21")))
# this will need careful adjustment by yourself
y_lab <- .25
## get first and last date from your data
lab_date <- range(df$date)
# this will need careful adjustment by yourself
x_lab <- c(2.75, 3)
x_points <- seq(x_lab[1], x_lab[2], len = 4)[1:3]

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df, aes(type, fill = type)) +
  ## for the arrow
  annotate(
    geom = "segment",
    x = x_lab[1], xend = x_lab[2], y = y_lab, yend = y_lab,
    arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(5, "pt")),
    color = "grey30"
  ) +
  ##  for the points
  geom_point(aes(x = x_points, y = y_lab), color = "grey30", stroke = NA, size = 2) +
  ## for the dates
  annotate(
    geom = "text",
    x = x_lab + c(-.1, .05), y = y_lab, label = format(lab_date, "%b\n%d,\n%Y"),
    hjust = 0,
    size = 8 * 5 / 14
  ) +
  ## now add a bit or margin to the right, otherwise text is cut
  theme(plot.margin = margin(r = 30)) +
  ## limit the plot to the data area and turn clipping off
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, length(unique(df$type))), clip = "off")
```

[image]